Excel Macro Runtime error: Method 'Copy' of 'Range' failed
I have an Excel VBA script that has been running fine for a year or more that has all of a sudden started acting up and throwing an error "Runtime error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Method 'Copy' of 'Range' failed" that is preventing the script from running and crashes Excel.
It fails when I run the portion of code that prints the pdf at line.
Sheets(Array("Daily Ship Summary", "Daily Receiving Summary")).Copy

There are a few functions in my code but it always seems to fail while trying to run Sub SaveSendQBCOGReport().
I have been googling and reading other replys on Stackoverflow and have not been able to figure out why this has all of a sudden started happening. Can someone please help?
My code is
Sub SaveSendQBCOGReport()

Dim xsht As Worksheet
Dim xRSht As Worksheet
Dim xShtemail As Worksheet
Dim xEmailTo As String
Dim xDate As String
Dim xFolder As String
Dim xRFolder As String
Dim xYesorNo As Integer
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim xEmailObj As Object
Dim xUsedRng As Range
Dim Answer As Integer
Dim AnswerFile As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim SentAt As String

Set xsht = Worksheets("Daily Ship Summary")
Set xRSht = Worksheets("Daily Receiving Summary")
Set xShtemail = Worksheets("eMail")

'Refresh all tables referenced in the workbook
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

' Get all emails
j = xShtemail.UsedRange.Columns("A").Rows.Count

For i = 1 To j
    xEmailTo = xEmailTo & ";" & xShtemail.Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i

SentAt = Format(DateTime.Now, "mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm")

'Get date and format for use in filename
xDate = Replace(xsht.Range("Date").Value, "/", "-")

'Set folder and filename for pdf
xFolder = "V:\MiniMRP Data\Linked Data\Daily COG Summary"
xFolder = xFolder + "\" + xDate + " Shipped COG Summary" + ".pdf"
xRFolder = "V:\MiniMRP Data\Linked Data\Daily Recieving Summary"
xRFolder = xRFolder + "\" + xDate + " Receiving Summary" + ".pdf"

'set print area Daily Ship Summary
Dim last_entry As Integer
last_entry = xsht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
xsht.PageSetup.PrintArea = Range("A1:F" & last_entry).Address

With xsht.PageSetup
.LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
.RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
.TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
.BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
.Orientation = xlLandscape
.CenterHorizontally = True
.FitToPagesWide = 1
.Zoom = False
End With
'ActiveSheet.PrintPreview

'set print area Receiving Summary
Dim last_entry_R As Integer
last_entry_R = xRSht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
xRSht.PageSetup.PrintArea = Range("A1:J" & last_entry_R).Address

With xRSht.PageSetup
.LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
.RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
.TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
.BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
.Orientation = xlLandscape
.CenterHorizontally = True
.FitToPagesWide = 1
.Zoom = False
End With
'ActiveSheet.PrintPreview

'print to pdf and send
Set xUsedRng = xsht.UsedRange
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xUsedRng.Cells) <> 0 Then
    'Save as PDF file
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Sheets(Array("Daily Ship Summary", "Daily Receiving Summary")).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=xFolder, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    If Answer = vbYes Then
        'xSht.Range("K8:M8").ClearContents
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'Create Outlook email
        Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)

        With xEmailObj
            '.Display
            .To = xEmailTo
            .Subject = "No-Reply - Daily Journal Entry COG Summary " + xDate
            .body = "See attached for COG summary for all inventory items marked booked for shipment in MiniMRP on " + xDate + "." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "This email has been sent automatically at " & SentAt & "." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "This inbox is not monitored."
            .Attachments.Add xFolder
            If DisplayEmail = False Then
            .Send
            End If
        End With
        
    End If
Else
  MsgBox "The active worksheet cannot be blank"
  Exit Sub
End If

Call AddRecordsIntoAccessTable

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub


Sub AddRecordsIntoAccessTable()
        
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'The macro opens the DailyCOGsLog.accdb database and adds the rows from the Table
    '"dailyshiplogQ" in the "DailyCOGsLog" table of the database.
    'The code uses late binding, so no reference to external library is required.
    
    'Written By:    Michael Moss
    'Date:          10/6/2023
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'Declaring the necessary variables.
    Dim accessFile  As String
    Dim accessTable As String
    Dim accessTable1 As String
    Dim sht         As Worksheet
    Dim xsht         As Worksheet
    Dim sht1         As Worksheet
    Dim tbl         As ListObject
    Dim tbl1         As ListObject
    Dim lastRow     As Long
    Dim lastColumn  As Integer
    Dim lastRow1     As Long
    Dim lastColumn1  As Integer
    Dim con         As Object
    Dim rs          As Object
    Dim rs1          As Object
    Dim sql         As String
    Dim sql1         As String
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim j           As Integer
            
    'Disable the screen flickering
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Specify the file path of the accdb file. You can also use the full path of the file like this:
    accessFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "DailyCOGsLog.accdb"
   
    'Set the name of the table you want to add the data.
    accessTable = "DailyCOGsLog"
    accessTable1 = "DailyInventoryLog"

    'Set the worksheet that contains the data.
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("dailyshiplogQ")
    Set xsht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Ship Summary")
    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("dailyinventoryvalueQ")
    Set tbl = sht.ListObjects("dailyshiplogQ")
    Set tbl1 = sht1.ListObjects("dailyinventoryvalueQ")
    
    'Set varible xDate to date on spreadsheet
    xDate = xsht.Range("Date").Value
    
    'Find the last row and last column in the given worksheet.
    With tbl
        lastRow = .ListRows.Count
        lastColumn = .ListColumns.Count
    End With

    With tbl1
        lastRow1 = .ListRows.Count
        lastColumn1 = .ListColumns.Count
    End With

    'MsgBox "Rows " & lastRow & " Columns " & lastColumn, vbOKCancel
    
    'Check if there are data in the worksheet.
    If lastRow < 1 Or lastColumn < 1 Then
        'MsgBox "There are no data in the given worksheet!", vbCritical, "Empty Data"
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    If lastRow1 < 1 Or lastColumn1 < 1 Then
        'MsgBox "There are no data in the given worksheet!", vbCritical, "Empty Data"
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    'Create the ADODB connection object.
    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
    
    'Check if the object was created.
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "The connection was not created!", vbCritical, "Connection Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Err.Clear
    
    'Open the connections.
    con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & accessFile
    'con1.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & accessFile1
    
    'Create the SQL statement to delete existing records for the date in question
    sqld = "DELETE " & accessTable & ".[Ship Date] FROM " & accessTable & " WHERE (((" & accessTable & ".[Ship Date])=#" & xDate & "#));"
    sqld1 = "DELETE " & accessTable1 & ".[DateOn] FROM " & accessTable1 & " WHERE (((" & accessTable1 & ".[DateOn])=#" & xDate & "#));"
                
    'Execute sqld and sqld1
    con.Execute (sqld)
    con.Execute (sqld1)
    
    'Create the SQL statement to retrieve the table data (the entire table).
    sql = "SELECT * FROM " & accessTable
    sql1 = "SELECT * FROM " & accessTable1
    
    'Create the ADODB recordset object.
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set rs1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    'Check if the object was created.
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set rs1 = Nothing
        Set con = Nothing
        MsgBox "The recordset was not created!", vbCritical, "Recordset Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Err.Clear
             
    'Set the necessary recordset properties.
    rs.CursorType = 1   'adOpenKeyset on early binding
    rs.LockType = 3     'adLockOptimistic on early binding
    rs1.CursorType = 1   'adOpenKeyset on early binding
    rs1.LockType = 3     'adLockOptimistic on early binding
        
    'Open the recordsets.
    rs.Open sql, con
    rs1.Open sql1, con
    
    'Add the records from Excel to Access by looping through the rows and columns of the given worksheet.
    'Here the headers are in the row 1 and they are identical to the Access table headers.
    'This is the reason why, for example, there are no spaces in the headers of the sample worksheet.
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        rs.AddNew
        For j = 1 To lastColumn
            'This is how it will look like the first time (i = 2, j = 1):
            'rs("FirstName") = "Bob"
            rs(tbl.HeaderRowRange(1, j).Value) = tbl.DataBodyRange(i, j).Value
        Next j
        rs.Update
    Next i
 
     For i = 1 To lastRow1
        rs1.AddNew
        For j = 1 To lastColumn1
            'This is how it will look like the first time (i = 2, j = 1):
            rs1(tbl1.HeaderRowRange(1, j).Value) = tbl1.DataBodyRange(i, j).Value
        Next j
        rs1.Update
    Next i
 
    'Close the recordet and the connection.
    rs.Close
    rs1.Close
    con.Close
    
    'Release the objects.
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set rs1 = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing
    
    'Re-enable the screen.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    
End Sub

Function FileExists(FilePath As String) As Boolean
 
    '--------------------------------------------------
    'Checks if a file exists (using the Dir function).
    '--------------------------------------------------
 
    On Error Resume Next
    If Len(FilePath) > 0 Then
        If Not Dir(FilePath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileExists = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
 
End Function


Try clearing the clipboard before the copy operation with Application.CutCopyMode = False

You're using ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll - are all queries set to not run in the background?  Might be a timing issue.
